# VoiceOver not focusing on back button

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have a problem with the behavior of VoiceOver when in my view there is a `UITableView`.

After selecting a cell of the table to trigger a segue if I go back to the ViewController VoiceOver jumps to the previously selected cell. 
In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I call `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` to prevent the cell to remain selected.

I tried posting a `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` or a `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` in `viewDidAppear` but nothing changes.

So my questions are: is this the correct behavior of VO? 
 What should I do to always focus on the back button when the view appears?

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass in the item that you want to have focused? such as:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem);
```

otherwise in `viewDidAppear` you could loop through all of the visible cells and turn off accessibility if focused, then turn it immediately back on

```
for(UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
    if (cell.accessibilityElementIsFocused) {
        cell.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
        });
    }
}
```

Definitely not an elegant approach, but may work in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks to the suggestion, I tried passing self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem but it didn't help. I ended up disabling the accessibility for all the views in the viewController for 0.1s and then re-enable it.

Answer (score 0):

This will focus the voiceover on first navigationBar element(the back button):

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, 
                     argument: navigationController?.navigationBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the tableView hidden for the voiceOver for a brief moment, focus on the back button and then make ir visible again. I had the same problem and it was the only thing that worked for me:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: self.navigationController?.navigationBar)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.tableView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
        }
    }
```